# Using an HttpContext to send more than one file to the client

Tags: asp.net, http, f#

I read this blog post about implementing an asp.net HTTP Handler in F#

http://codinglight.blogspot.ca/2010/03/writing-your-own-httphandler-in-f.html

I did it successfully and sent an HTML file back to the client. Now, I wanted to do something less basic and send a more complex HTML file with styling and images embedded in it. So I sent an HTML file with stylings that included a background image property. The problem is the browser did not have the image on hand to display it. Now I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get another file sent to the client.

The blog post did not leave me with a lot have extra information about how to continue and I have a poor understanding of how HTTP is used to interact with the browser. So, all I have is and HTTP context object, which comes with a lot but I don't know how to use it properly.

The best I've come up with is the following code. It sends the HTML but the image it's just dumped onto the page.

```
open System.Web;
open System.IO;
open System;

type HttpHandler() = 
    let path = """c:\users\---\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\Highnote\Highnote\"""
    let imgHeader =  """HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n
                        Content-Type: image/gif\r\n
                        Content-Length: [length in bytes of the image]\r\n
                        \r\n"""
    interface IHttpHandler with
        member this.ProcessRequest (context:HttpContext) =
            let response = context.Response
            let request = context.Request

            response.TransmitFile(path + "index.html")
            //response.Clear()

            response.AppendHeader("ImageHeader", imgHeader)
            response.TransmitFile(path + "photo.jpg")

            response.End()
        member this.IsReusable with get() = true
```

How would I be able to mimic sending additional files and directories to the browser with the resources I have?

Comment: HTTP 1.1. is stateless. What browsers do is that they get an HTML page, and then issue a new request for each new resource required. You'll need to look at the incoming request in order to examine whether it's a request for an HTML page, an image, a CSS file, etc.